Непонятная ситуация с метками [авторизация], [аутентификация] и [auth]
Описание
Хочу показать вам таблицу информации об этих метках:



Метка
Руководство по использованию
Описание метки




авторизация
Авторизация — процесс проверки, что пользователь, программа или устройство имеет право на доступ к защищённому ресурсу. Смотри также аутентификация.



аутентификация

Аутентификация это процедура проверки подлинности, не путать с авторизацией


auth
Используйте данную метку если Ваш вопрос связан с Авторизацией и/или Аутентификацией.
Авториза́ция (англ. authorization «разрешение; уполномочивание») — предоставление определённому лицу или группе лиц прав на выполнение определённых действий; а также процесс проверки (подтверждения) данных прав при попытке выполнения этих действий.Авторизацию не следует путать с аутентификацией — процедурой проверки легальности пользователя или данных, например, проверки соответствия введённого пользователем пароля к учётной записи паролю в базе данных, или проверка цифровой подписи письма по ключу шифрования, или проверка контрольной суммы файла на соответствие заявленной автором этого файла. Авторизация же производит контроль доступа к различным ресурсам системы в процессе работы легальных пользователей после успешного прохождения ими аутентификации.



Вопрос
Что с ними не так?
Почему описание авторизация написана в руководстве по использованию?
Почему описание метки аутентификация больше похоже на руководство по использованию, чем на описание?
Почему руководство по использованию auth предлагает использовать себя вместо авторизация и аутентификация. В чем вообще смысл этой метки?
И почему описания авторизация и аутентификация слиты и написаны в auth вместо того чтобы отдельно быть со своей меткой?

"Почему описание авторизация написана в руководстве по использованию?
Почему описание метки аутентификация больше похоже на руководство по использованию, чем на описание?" - потому что, каждый как хочет (как понимает), так и делает. При приеме правок описаний меток большинство вообще не проверяют, это руководство по использованию или описание.

Ну и правки описаний меток принимаются всего 2 голосами, с большой вероятностью правка принимается не очень опытными участниками.

По вопросу — тут я не вижу смысла как-то тщательно разбирать, почему так получилось. Нужно просто привести к нормальному виду описания, и auth сининимизировать на аутентификацию (authentification).

@insolor ну да. Просто хотел привлечь внимание к описаниям, которые больше путают, чем помогают.
